# How to parse an Xml having two tags with same name

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using SAX parser to get a data from XML. unfortunately i am having two tags with same name example `<tags> <sametag>Abc</sametag> <sametag>Def</sametag ></tags>`. so whenever i am parsing the file i only getting ABC the same tag which contains different data will never parse. if anyone having idea for to parse same name tags pls guide me to solve.

Comment: Any chance to show the code from your Sax Parser where you actually (try to) get the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/):

```
@Root(name = "tags")
class Tags {
    @ElementList(entry = "sametag", inline = "true")
    public ArrayList<String> sameTags;
}
```

I have totally not tested that code but you get the gist as to how easy it is to use. To see [how to use it in Android](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/) take a look at my blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post could help you http://codeofaninja.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-how-to-parse-xml-file-and.html